# How to avoid high CPU utilization in dequeue thread when using producer-consumer type queues

Tags: android, sockets, queue, cpu-usage, blockingqueue

I am using UDP sockets form which packets are enqueued to *linked blocking queue* in android. For a single queue, 2 threads are used, one thread is responsible for enqueue elements in the queue and other to dequeue elements. For both of enqueue and dequeue threads, a `while(true)` loop is used. However, `while(true)` in *enqueue thread* don't consume a significant memory as shown in android studio profiler. My conjecture is that this is due to blocking nature of `udpSocket.receive(packet)` nature. The best part is that enqueue thread having `while(true)` is consuming ~ 0 % memory as shown the android profiler. However, the `dequeuing thread` consumed ~ 15% memory as shown in below screenshot. The code snippet for dequeue thread is shown below

```
 while (true) {

            if (!linkedBlockingQueue_A.isEmpty()) {

                String  data = (String) linkedBlockingQueue_A.element();

//                System.out.println(data);

                // parsing the data
                String[] tupleData =  data.split(",");
                Integer sensor_id = Integer.valueOf(tupleData[0]);
                Integer tuple_id = Integer.valueOf(tupleData[1]);
                Long generation_time = Long.valueOf(tupleData[4]);
                Long sensor_data = Long.valueOf(tupleData[5]);
                Long event_arrival_time = Long.valueOf(tupleData[6]);
                Long event_ingestion_time = nanoTime();


//              define stream ecg_stream (sensorID int, tupleID int, ecg_value float , event_ingestion_time_ecg long, event_arrival_time_ecg long);";

                        // sending data to siddhi server
                   inputHandlerA.send(new Object[]{sensor_id, tuple_id, sensor_data,generation_time, event_arrival_time ,  event_ingestion_time });

                linkedBlockingQueue_A.remove();
            }
```

I think what is need is some blocking nature in dequeue thread to avoid memory consumption due to polling. As I am using multiple sockets, my device "google pixel" is so hot after some hours of operations, that I have to shut it off for few hours.

any suggestions are most welcome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved as I figured out that `queue.take()` is what I was looking for. As it retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this deque (in other words, the first element of this deque), waiting if necessary until an element becomes available. Below is the updated code.

```
        while (true) {

                String  data = (String) linkedBlockingQueue_A.take();


                // parsing the data
                String[] tupleData =  data.split(",");
                Integer sensor_id = Integer.valueOf(tupleData[0]);
                Integer tuple_id = Integer.valueOf(tupleData[1]);
                Long generation_time = Long.valueOf(tupleData[4]);
                Long sensor_data = Long.valueOf(tupleData[5]);
                Long event_arrival_time = Long.valueOf(tupleData[6]);
                Long event_ingestion_time = nanoTime();


//              define stream ecg_stream (sensorID int, tupleID int, ecg_value float , event_ingestion_time_ecg long, event_arrival_time_ecg long);";

                        // sending data to siddhi server
                   inputHandlerA.send(new Object[]{sensor_id, tuple_id, sensor_data,generation_time, event_arrival_time ,  event_ingestion_time });
//
           }
```

For the same `while(true)` the utilization is low because of blocking/waiting nature of the `take()` method

[image]